# Securing a web folder with out membership roles defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, directory, membership

Our site is hosted on a shared server. We have a login module independent of any membership roles. We have not used this feature.Our login db table only has email id and pwd fields. 
One of our folders (General) contains sensitive documents: pdf; jpg; doc files etc. We do not want this folder to be accessed by unauthorized users as well as any search engines such as google, yahoo and others.
We added the below lines in the web config

```
<location path="General" allowOverride="true">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="Administrators" />
    <deny users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
   </location>
```

This change in web config has secured the folder as accessing the folder results in permission denied message etc. However, now we want our logged in users to be able to access this folder. We tried adding the below line for logged in users:
 Roles.CreateRole("Administrators");
However, this is resulting in an error ; and it seems asp.net is trying to create membership table and is unable to.
Is it possible to forcibly assign a  Role to a user by completely ignoring the Membership part?

We are not using sqlaspent tables and no plans to use it.
We are also not using ASP.NET Membership framework.

Original question reframed: (  allow roles="Administrators"   line removed from web config)

```
<location path="General" allowOverride="true">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
              <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
       </location>
```

The above changes in web config results in Access Denied for all files in General folder. Is it possible to (1) modify web config during run time and change deny users to allow users in say general/test.aspx page load section or (2) load a different web config from a different folder in general/test.aspx page load?

Comment: Could you post the error message, I would have said that you need to deny Anonymous Users and then allow the roles that need access to the folder.

Comment: Makes no difference where the database is stored. The membership provider will manage the user authentication and the roleprovider will handle the roles. Once loaded they will then use the current users credentials and then check what access permissions they are due from the membership provider. Basically the <authorization> section acts as a ACL.

Comment: Error message added to the original post. Also, like I mentioned that we are not using the membership role functionality anywhere in our application.  Thnx

Comment: Is it a remote database on a server? OR is it a SQLExpress database that is stored in the App_Data Directory being referenced by the ConnectionString

Comment: Remote database is hosted on a remote third party hosting. We do not have just  anything in the App_data folder- neither on our local or remote web folder.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a database connection issue. Your remote provider allows connections to your DB remotely? Can you connect to it using SQL Server Management Studio?

Some shared hosting providers don't allow remote access to SQL Servers.

Answer (score 0):

have you installed into database the sqlaspent tables?

If not yo need to using [Aspnet SQl Server Registration Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862.ASPX), create the correct structure table into database(which roles has been stored).

Create a membershipuser like an administrator, Jojom,Angelina Jolie or what you prefer with it's own property)
Create default roles (customer,administrator etc)

bind user to membership and then you will able to use authorization rules.

your method say only to aspnet that only administrator member which are visibile via   Context.User.IsInRole("Administrator") can access to this page ....but to be an administrator you need to be stored into a database or in a custom provider......

Comment: Thanks. See last 2 lines of original post - just added for more clarity.

Comment: Hi Shankar, i think this post could help you [Don’t Depend Upon the ASP.NET Membership Tables](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/03/05/38558/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way assigning a Role to a user without using a membership provider. One thing I can think of, is giving up the location sector at the web config and start monitoring every request to the application using the Global.asax Application_BeginRequest method and check if the request is to the restricted folder and if the user loged in (session).

Another way is to use some kind of httpHandler to do the save thing.

**Edit:**
In your login form, once a user authenticated by his username and password assign a session variable that notes this user is Administartor.

```
void Login()
{
    //check user+password
    //...
    if(UserIsAuthenticated)
    {
        Session["Administrator"] = true;
        //more stuff to do with authenticate user
    }
}
```

and in your Global.asax:

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Request.PhysicalPath.Contains("RestrictedFolderName")//you can do a more profound check here
    {
         if((bool)Session["Administrator"])
             //all ok - do nothing
         else
             //not authorized user trying to access folder- do redirect or somthing 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. My mind is firing up. How do we check user logged in (session) considering we are not using Membership framework.

Comment: Thanks Issac. I can restrict the access to a folder with that. However, I am still struggling (4 hours now!) to obtain the value of Session["Administrator"]. It keeps throwing System.NullReferenceException. I tried Application_AcquireRequestState also, so far no luck. Once I am able to check the Session["Administrator"] - I guess it would be solved. Hopefully, if I deny access to a folder in global asax will search engines google , yahoo etc. be disciplined or they would still find way to crawl into restricted folder?

Comment: Where do you assign the Session["Administrator"]? you need to check if its null before trying to parse it. search engine crawlers act much as anonymous users, so they cant acces a folder that needs a session assigned to authenticated users. you can always restrict access of crawlers by using Robots.txt file

Comment: Thanks. I have a Session["Userlogged"] = ok that fires  up when a user is logged in. In the Global asax I am indeed checking: (1) if Session["Userlogged"] is null prevent access to restricted folder.(2) if Session["Userlogged"] = ok  then allow access. Problem is the session is always returning null value from global asax . I tried Application_AcquireRequestState and other stuff but this null reference error message sticks out.